# Converting RGBA, HSL and HSLA colors to RGB (or in a java.awt.Color object)

Tags: java, css, rgb, rgba, hsl

I'm looking for a description of algorithms for converting RGBA, HSL and HSLA colors to RGB color, or a library for converting them in an java.awt.Color object.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

With the new info from the comments, I'll change this to reflect what you have versus what you need.

First, we need to parse the rgb/hsl string. This can be done pretty easily using a couple regular expressions and `String.split`:

```
private static final Pattern hexRegex = Pattern.compile("#[\\dA-Fa-f]{6}");
private static final Pattern rgbRegex = Pattern.compile("rgba?\\([^)]*\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
private static final Pattern hlsRegex = Pattern.compile("hlsa?\\([^)]*\\)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

The first `Pattern` matches any hex-encoded value. The second one matches `rgb(something)` or `rgba(something)`. The third one is the same as the second one, but with `hsl` and `hsla`. To use these:

```
public static int[] getRGB(String cssString) {
    if (hexRegex.matcher(cssString).matches())
        return getRgbFromHex(cssString);
    if (rgbRegex.matcher(cssString).matches())
        return getRgbFromRgb(cssString);
    if (hslRegex.matcher(cssString).matches())
        return getRgbFromHsl(cssString);
    return null; // no match
}

private static int[] getRgbFromHex(String hexString) {
    int rgb = Integer.decode(hexString);
    Color c = new Color(rgb);
    return new int[] { c.getRed(), c.getGreen(), c.getBlue(), c.getAlpha() };
}

private static int[] getRgbFromRgb(String rgbString) {
    String[] values = rgbString.split("[\\s,()]");
    // values[0] is just "rgb" or "rgba"
    String red = values[1];
    String green = values[2];
    String blue = values[3];
    String alpha = "1.0";
    if (values.length >= 5) {
        alpha = values[4];
    }
    return new int[] {
        parseValue(red, 255),
        parseValue(green, 255),
        parseValue(blue, 255),
        parseAlpha(alpha),
    };
}

private static int[] getRgbFromHsl(String hslString) {
    String[] values = hslString.split("[\\s,()]");
    // values[0] is just "hsl" or "hsla"
    String hue = values[1];
    String sat = values[2];
    String light = values[3];
    String alpha = "1.0";
    if (values.length >= 5) {
        alpha = values[4];
    }
    int h = parseValue(hue, 360);
    double s = parsePercent(sat);
    double l = parsePercent(light);
    int a = parseAlpha(alpha);
    return hslToRgb(h, s, l, a);
}

private static int[] hslToRgb(int h, double s, double l, int a) {
    // TODO Calculate me
    int r = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;
    return new int[] { r, g, b, a };
}

private static int parseValue(String val, int max) {
    if (val.endsWith("%")) {
        return (int) (parsePercent(val) * max);
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(val);
}

private static double parsePercent(String perc) {
    return Integer.parseInt(perc.substring(0, perc.length() - 1)) / 100.0;
}

private static int parseAlpha(String alpha) {
    return (int) (Double.parseDouble(alpha) * 255);
}
```

Here's what everything does:

- `getRGB` - Takes the CSS string, determines its format, then proceeds to parsing it. Returns `null` if it can't determine the format (i.e., it's invalid). The array returned will be 4 elements, r, g, b, and a, and all values will be between 0 and 255.
- `getRgbFromHex` - Uses `Integer.decode` to parse it since this does `#` hex numbers for us, then uses `Color` to get the RGB values.
- `getRgbFromRgb` - Parses for the values from an `rgb` string (includes `rgba`). Splits the string on whitespace, commas, or parentheses, then parses each individual value and creates an array from them.
- `getRgbFromHsl` - Behaves similarly to `getRgbFromRgb`, but with HSL values and the appropriate parsing instead of the RGB parsing.
- `hslToRgb` - This is your calculation logic that you said you've already done in your comments. Just calculate the `int` values of r, g, and b here from h, s, and l, and this method will work.
- `parseValue` - If it's a percentage, it returns the parsed percentage times the value of `max`, otherwise, it simply parses it as an `int` using `Integer.parseInt`.
- `parsePercent` - Parses the integer part of the string and returns the value as a `double` divided by 100.
- `parseAlpha` - Parses the alpha as a `double` and returns it times 255.

Testing with rgb/rgba confirms that this works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRGB("#FF00CC")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRGB("rgb(255,0,0)")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRGB("rgba(255,0,0,0.5)")));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getRGB("rgba(100%,0%,30%,0.5)")));
}
```

This prints:

```
[255, 0, 204, 255]
[255, 0, 0, 255]
[255, 0, 0, 127]
[255, 0, 76, 127]
```

One other thing you may want to consider is using rounding instead of casting directly to `int` for the percentage stuff. This would improve the accuracy of the percentages.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Color.HSBtoRGB` and `Color.RGBtoHSB`. For example:

```
int r = 0, g = 255, b = 255;
float[] hsb = Color.RGBtoHSB(r, g, b, null);
for (float f : hsb) {
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

This outputs:

```
0.5
1.0
1.0
```

These three `float` values are the H, S, and B values respectively. For colors with alpha, the alpha doesn't change from RGB to HSB, so `A == A`.

To create a `Color` with the returned array:

```
Color color = Color.getHSBColor(hsb[0], hsb[1], hsb[2]);
```

I can't help you much more without more details about what exactly you want as input and output.

---

**Edit:** See my other answer.

Comment: My goal is to convert all the CSS Legal Color Values ( http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp ) to RGB.
Converting Hexadecimal Colors and Color Names is easy, i'm looking for a RGBA, HSL and HSLA conversion. 
Your method doesn't work, HSL and HSB are different representations' systems.

Comment: @AntonioGiovanniSchiavone So what do you have for input then? Something like `rgb(0,255,255)` or `#00FFFF`? If you need to parse down to that value, here's [a good CSS parser](https://github.com/corgrath/osbcp-css-parser) for Java. Can I assume this is what you have for input? The actual property value from CSS as a string?

Comment: @AntonioGiovanniSchiavone Also, sorry about the HSB/HSL thing, I totally misread your post :X I'll fix it once I know what you're looking for.

Comment: As described in the link above, for the HSL I have an input as "hsl(220,100%,63%)", my output is an array [r,g,b]. For HSL I resolved implementing this algorithm http://www.geekymonkey.com/Programming/CSharp/RGB2HSL_HSL2RGB.htm.
Still needing help for RGBA and HSLA.

Comment: @AntonioGiovanniSchiavone the extra `A` is just the alpha (transparency) value, which AFAIK doesn't change from RGBA to HSLA. In other words, no conversion should be needed to translate A to A. You may want to consider making your output array have 4 parameters, `[r, g, b, a]`, and make `a` default to 100% alpha (255, 1.0, or 100%) if it's not specified (this is the default otherwise). I'll update my answer in a little bit, I can't ATM.

Comment: Do you mean that rgb(r,g,b) and rgba(r,g,b,a) (with a included in [0-1]) are ALWAYS the same color?

And also do you mean that hsl(h,s%,l%) and hsla(h,s%,l%,a) (with a included in [0-1]) are ALWAYS the same color?
(I'm not an expert in colors' rapresentations)

Comment: @AntonioGiovanniSchiavone In a sense, they are the same color, but with different _transparency_. This means that they may _appear_ differently since they may blend with the background, but the base color is the same. In other words, `rgb(255,0,0)` (red, completely opaque) is exactly the same as `rgb(255,0,0,1.0)` (red, completely opaque). `rgb(255,0,0,0.5)` is the same base color (red), but is half transparent (a.k.a translucent). On a white background, it will appear lighter than its opaque counterpart, but it will appear differently on say a green background. I'll update my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex rules don't work fine, because they allow uncorrect string (such as "rgba(1000,500%,500%,2)" ) and deny correct form (such as "#fff" ).

I wrote more strict and correct regex rules:

```
    String keywords_color_regex = "^[a-z]*$";
    String hex_color_regex = "^#[0-9a-f]{3}([0-9a-f]{3})?$";
    String rgb_color_regex = "^rgb\\(\\s*(0|[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\s*,\\s*(0|[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\s*,\\s*(0|[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\s*\\)$";
    String rgba_color_regex = "^rgba\\(\\s*(0|[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\s*,\\s*(0|[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\s*,\\s*(0|[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\s*,\\s*((0.[1-9])|[01])\\s*\\)$";
    String hsl_color_regex = "^hsl\\(\\s*(0|[1-9]\\d?|[12]\\d\\d|3[0-5]\\d)\\s*,\\s*((0|[1-9]\\d?|100)%)\\s*,\\s*((0|[1-9]\\d?|100)%)\\s*\\)$";
```

For rgba and hsla, my goal is to calculate the actual color displayed. So I was wondering if, given an rgba/hsla color and its background color, there's a way to "mix" them to calculate the displayed color...